# Всем привет, есть код для определения, является ли, введенное число однозначным, двузначным или трехзначным

Tags: javascript

Помогите поменять его так чтобы вместо окон все отображалось на странице

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>

var num = prompt('Введите число', 0);

if (num == 0) {
  alert( "Число " + num + " нуль" );
} else if (num > 0 && num < 10) {
  alert( "Число " + num + " однозначное положительное" );
} else if (num >= 10 && num < 100) {
  alert( "Число " + num + " двухзначное положительное" );
} else if (num >= 100) {
  alert( "Число " + num + " положительное трехзначное и более" );
} else if (num < 0 && num > -10) {
  alert( "Число " + num + " однозначное отрицательное" );
} else if (num <= -10 && num > -100) {
  alert( "Число " + num + " двухзначное отрицательное" );
} else {
  alert( "Число " + num + " отрицательное трехзначное и более" );
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

введите сюда код

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: "_Помогите поменять..._" — меняйте! Мы в Вас верим! У Вас всё получится! (Такая помощь подойдёт?)

Comment: Всем спасибо за комментарии) Я так понимаю, что никто не поможет?

Comment: @Florth: что **конкретно** у Вас не получается? Пока не видно даже попыток. Сделать за Вас и помочь - это не одно и то же.

Comment: Я не понимаю как заменить алерт, наверное это что-то очень простое, но я, к сожалению, не достаточно хорошо развит для решения этого задания

Comment: Просто вставь это вместо того что у тебя
<script>
var num = prompt('Введите число', 0), znak, lng;
num > 0 ? [znak = "положительное.",lng = num.length] : [znak = "отрицательное.",lng = num.length-1];
document.body.innerHTML = "Число " + num + " / " + lng + " значное " + znak;
</script>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вам нужно чтобы отрисовывалось все на странице? В таком случае нужно использовать элементы HTML, а не `alert`

Чтобы решить вашу проблему будет достаточно заменить alert на `document.getElementByTag('body').innerHTML = "%значение%"` и в итоге получим вот такой код:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>

  let num = prompt('Введите число', 0)
  let body = document.querySelector('body')
  if (num == 0) {
    body.innerHTML = 'Число ' + num + ' нуль'
  } else if (num > 0 && num < 10) {
    body.innerHTML = 'Число ' + num + ' однозначное положительное'
  } else if (num >= 10 && num < 100) {
    body.innerHTML = 'Число ' + num + ' двухзначное положительное'
  } else if (num >= 100) {
    body.innerHTML = 'Число ' + num + ' положительное трехзначное и более'
  } else if (num < 0 && num > -10) {
    body.innerHTML = 'Число ' + num + ' однозначное отрицательное'
  } else if (num <= -10 && num > -100) {
    body.innerHTML = 'Число ' + num + ' двухзначное отрицательное'
  } else {
    body.innerHTML = 'Число ' + num + ' отрицательное трехзначное и более'
  }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Сразу скажу, что сам алгоритм, как и код в целом ужасен, но я думаю вы это поправите, если вам действительно будет нужно

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Ну, возможно, стоило и prompt заменить на инпут? А сейчас как-то наполовину.

Comment: И стоило бы не в каждом Ифе присваивать к боди, а присваивать переменной и потом боди менять на значение переменной. Иначе так вы замучаетесь потом менять под другой блок или еще что-то..